# Accesing Homestead Vagrant from LAN via URL

Tags: vagrant, homestead, hosts

I'm trying to set up the hosts file in my laptop to allow connecting to my Vagrant box on my PC via URL, instead of just IP.

The IP part worked by itself just fine, I had to enter the IP of my PC, for example: **192.168.1.15:8000** and I got connected to the default website. Now here's my first question actually, why do I get connected to one particular website, even though I have two.

My homestead.yaml file looks as such:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ssh_key.pub

keys:
    - ssh_key

folders:
    - map: /HomesteadCode
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/public
    - map: phpmyadmin.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/phpmyadmin
```

But I get connected to what is homestead.app. How would I then connect to phpmyadmin.dev?

And my other question is, how do I set up the hosts file on my laptop to allow connecting using the URL? I set up the hosts as such:

```
192.168.1.21  homestead.app
192.168.1.21  phpmyadmin.dev
```

and it didn't work, even if i entered homestead.app:8000 into the browser.

And the last question, why does it work on ym local PC, even if I set up the hosts file like so:

```
192.168.10.10  homestead.app
192.168.1.21  homestead.app
192.168.1.21  phpmyadmin.dev
192.168.10.10 phpmyadmin.dev
```

Even if there are two entries for homestead, one seemingly wrong, it still works.

Comment: by default it configures a private network so can you ping 192.168.10.10 from your PC ? can you confirm if you go to 192.168.10.10 from your browser on PC it opens a page ?

Comment: yes, going to 192.168.10.10  does open the page. however going to 192.168.1.21 (the PC LAN IP address) does not.

Comment: but why do you want 192.168.1.21 to resolve something running on your VM ?

Comment: i don't. i'm just curious as to why adding it to hosts doesn't break functionality. :)

what I actually want to do is to enable "Lan-wide url functionality" so to speak. I don't know what the technically correct term for that is. So what I am struggling to accomplish is to enter homestead.app on my laptop and for it to connect to my PC vagrant box.

--thanks for your time! :)

Comment: on your laptop host file, you add `192.168.10.10  homestead.app` so you can connect using the fully qualified name

Comment: but isn't 192.168.10.10 the IP of the virtual machine? And so can only be accessed from the computer that actually has vagrant installed?

Comment: you can check https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes vbox has few different network mode that can accommodate different needs, vagrant does not even map them all but enough to work

Comment: While not exactly your question, you might want to take a look at ngrok.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/any-comprehensive-guide-to-make-a-homestead-vm-available-through-the-local-network